# How to create a library template which can be updated and update existing libraries

Tags: document-template, template

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a document library template (eg called 'doclibrary') which can be used to create doclibrary1, doclibrary2 etc - but when the original doclibrary is udpate (eg add a new column) then the column gets rolled out to all other libraries based upon the original template.

Comment: Would all of your libraries be on the same site collection? I'd look at creating a custom content type and using that content type in each library rather than a library template.